# Latest security updates with debootstrap?

Tags: system-installation, debootstrap

After running debootstrap I have to chroot into the system and run `# apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` to apply security updates.

Is it possible for debootstrap to use the latest packages, so I don't have to update the system manually afterwards?

Answer (score 4):

From Debian Wiki, Debootstrap, https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap:

> Debootstrap can only use one repository for its packages. If you need to merge packages from different repositories (the way apt does) to make a rootfs, or you need to automatically customise the rootfs, then use Multistrap, https://wiki.debian.org/Multistrap.